# how do I set up local testing in browserstack

Tags: browserstack

I am using browserstack to test some devices, like IE. However I need to set up local testing so I can test my site `localhost:3000`

I have logged in to browserstack in Chrome and installed the extension. I click on the extension IE11 link. It takes me to a IE11 on Windows 8 virtual machine.

I type `localhost:3000` into IE but it doesn't seem to work.

Then I click the Settings cog and click resolve all URLs through my network.

Still it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: oops it seems in IE I need to use `http://localhost:3000` as it doesn't automatically resolve the protocol *http* silly mistake :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the setup was fine in Browserstack, I just forgot that in IE11 I need to use `http://localhost:3000` as it doesn't automatically resolve the protocol `http` silly mistake :)

Comment: Just leaving this here, maybe it will help someone else too:
http://localhost:3000 didn't work for me, but replacing localhost with my IPv4 IP address worked.